# syntax error in expression (error token is :)

Tags: bash, for-loop, syntax

below is my script to add command line arguments and print the output.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
for n in "$@":
do
        sum=$(($sum + $n))
done
echo $sum
```

But I am getting below error can someone help.

```
ubuntu@taskserver:~/var/save/Task$ ./SumAll.sh 1 2 7 7
./SumAll.sh: line 5: 10 + 7:: syntax error in expression (error token is ":")
10
```

add command line arguments and print the output.

Comment: There is no `:` in the syntax of the [`for` command](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-for). There must be a semicolon (`;`) or a newline before the `do` keyword.

Comment: See: `help for`

Comment: Why do you write a colon at the end of the last element in the list? In your example, the loop would go over `1 2 7 7:`, which means that on the last iteration, the variable `n` has the value `7:`. This is indeed not a valid numbber. BTW, if you read the error message carefully, this is exactly what it says.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is here:

```
for n in "$@":
```

Believe it or not, this is doing string concatenation, adding a `:` to the end of the user input. It's trying to execute `1 + 2:` which is a syntax error.

Not related to your question, but you should also install the Shellcheck extension for your editor. It doesn't catch this issue, but will catch other issues with your script.

Remove the `:`. Loops don't have colons in Bash.